# unique identifier on iOS that user can reset

Tags: ios, unique, anonymous, idfa

In my iOS app, I am looking for a unique identifier to use to be able distinguish between users but for the users to be completely anonymous to us who are providing the app.

Scenario: I am building "make comments" function in the app which will be sent to a moderator before being published in the discussion area in the app. The user's identity should be anonymous to me and to anyone who may hack into my system storage that contains discussion content (think GDPR).

1. The best iOS library option seems to be identifierForVendor, but the user has no easy control over resetting that identifier.
2. I like the IDFA library more, as the user can be completely anonymous and at their discretion set their identifier to all zeroes using built-in Apple settings. BUT I am not serving advertising. Is Apple still rejecting apps that use IDFA but have no ads?
3. Other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the IDFA, a valid and fair use for it is also for install attribution, so use this if it applies to your case. Another alternative would be a custom keychain-based solution that would store a UUID plus a mechanism for enabling the user to reset it at will. Finally, you could also use `UserDefaults` or a database if you don't care for cross-installation persistence.

Comment: I looked around for more details on install attribution, and what I found was not encouraging. E.g. "iOS 10+, LAT users’ IDFA can not be used for any purpose, including attribution." from [https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003734626-How-Does-Apple-s-Limit-Ad-Tracking-Affect-Attribution-][How Does Apple's Limit Ad Tracking Affect Attribution?]

Comment: Sure, but that's the user's decision after all (and their right to not be tracked). Honestly though, in your case, since you are not using this information for marketing reasons, a custom solution involving the keychain, coupled with a message and/or a setting to reset this information, would be more than ok. [Here is an article](https://medium.com/@miguelcma/persistent-cross-install-device-identifier-on-ios-using-keychain-ac9e4f84870f) I stumbled upon recently on this subject